# Drupal node form | Have a .tpl theme file for each node type?

Tags: drupal

I want to have something like node-type-form.tpl.php in my theme to control the layout of a few of my different content type node forms.  I know that I should be able to put something in my template.php to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at that module: [Node form template](http://drupal.org/project/node_form_template)

Comment: This is a great module!  I just ended up using this.

Answer (score 0):

In your template.php, you can create a preprocess function.
In this preprocess function, you can edit the template files like this:

```
if($variables['teaser'] == 1) {
    $variables['template_files'][] = "node-" . $variables['node']->type ."-teaser";
}
```

Comment: What was the function name you used? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: I added it to Garlands preprocess function.  It does work for default node types, but would not work for my custom content types.